# Cuantas veces se repite un valor en una lista

Tags: python, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Necesito saber cual es la película que mas se reprodujo en diferentes cines, tengo esta lista:

```
[['Memoria letal', 'cinemacenter'], ['Mortal Kombat', 'cinepolis'], ['Monster House', 
'cinemark'], ['Memoria letal', 'cinemark'], ['Maximo riesgo', 'cinepolis'], ['Mortal Kombat', 'cinemark'], ['Monster House', 'cinepolis'], ['Maximo riesgo', 'cinemacenter'], ['Mad Max', 'cinemark'], ['Mortal Kombat', 'cinemacenter']]
```

Por ejemplo si mortal kombat aparece en diferentes cines y mas que las demas, entonces el resultado deberia ser:

`print(('La pelicula mas reproducida es {}, en un total de {} cines').format(pelicula,cantidad de cines))`

Comment: ¿Qué se te ha ocurrido hasta el momento? Este sitio ayuda con dudas puntuales y concretas, pero no debe ser usado para dar simplemente el enunciado y que alguien te programe la solución. No es el objetivo del sitio, ni aprenderás mucho así. Las respuestas que obtengas podrían estar usando librerias o conocimientos que aún no tienes o no puedes usar. Mejor intentalo con lo que sabes, muestra hasta donde has llegado y pregunta por lo que te impide seguir.

Comment: Lo unico que se me a ocurrido hasta ahora es instanciar a cada cine y sacar el valor de cada uno, pero es bastante inmantenible

Answer (score 2):

para contar cuantas veces se repite un elemento usas `lista.count('elemento')` y para obtener el valor mas repetido usas la libreria `collections`
ejemplo:

```
from collections import Counter
lista=['burro','caballo','burro']
k=Counter(lista).most_common()[0][0]
h=lista.count(k)
print(k)
print(h)
```

espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

La librería **statistics** ofrece la función necesaria para obtener la moda, luego, para obtener la cantidad de cines, haces un conteo de las veces que se repite (ya que en este caso solo se repite 1 vez por cine).

Espero te sirva.

```
import statistics as stat

lista = [['Memoria letal', 'cinemacenter'], ['Mortal Kombat', 'cinepolis'], ['Monster House', 'cinemark'], ['Memoria letal', 'cinemark'], ['Maximo riesgo', 'cinepolis'], 
['Mortal Kombat', 'cinemark'], ['Monster House', 'cinepolis'], ['Maximo riesgo', 'cinemacenter'], ['Mad Max', 'cinemark'], ['Mortal Kombat', 'cinemacenter']]

peliculas = [ x[0] for x in lista ]     # Obienes la lista de todas las peliculas
pelicula_moda = stat.mode(peliculas)    # Obtienes la moda (la pelicula que más se repite)
cantidad_de_cines = peliculas.count(pelicula_moda)      # Verificas cuántas veces se repite la pelicula

print(('La pelicula mas reproducida es {}, en un total de {} cines').format(pelicula_moda, cantidad_de_cines))
```